# Configure map reduce on cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I plan to deploy my application on the Cloud Foundry cloud. My application requires hadoop to be configured, so I plan to set it up on Cloud Foundry micro instances. I'd be using two nodes - One being the master, and the other data node. Is there any documentation available anywhere to do this on cloud foundry? Does cloud foundry offer any support for map reduce?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can if you create your Hadoop cluster as multiple standalone applications http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/11/running-standalone-web-applications-on-cloud-foundry/

For a two nodes you have to:
- deploy a zookeeper node
- deploy a namenode and then a datanode
- deploy a a jobtracker and then a tasktracker

I think this is a little bit funcky, but this is possible.

With a micro instance, you have some limitation by default, like the 2G of memory max http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/infrastructure/micro/using-mcf.html Don't forget to increase it.